# Getting last 5 char of string with mysql query

Tags: mysql, varchar

I have to get last 5 numbers using mysql.

My values are like `YOT-A78514`,`LOP-C4521` ...

I have to get only last five char . How can I do this in query?

Comment: Why don't you look at the answer here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12504985/how-to-take-last-four-characters-from-a-varchar

Answer (score 134, accepted):

You can do this with [**RIGHT(str,len)**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_right) function. Returns the rightmost **len** characters from the string **str**,

Like below:

```
SELECT RIGHT(columnname,5) as yourvalue FROM tablename
```

Answer (score 18):

"Right"-function is the way to, using the substring may lead to an problem that is not so easy to notice:

```
mysql> select right('hello', 6);
+-------------------+
| right('hello', 6) |
+-------------------+
| hello             |
+-------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select substring('hello', -6);
+------------------------+
| substring('hello', -6) |
+------------------------+
|                        |
+------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

But if you don't try to go past the start of the string, then substring of course works fine:

```
mysql> select substring('hello', -5);
+------------------------+
| substring('hello', -5) |
+------------------------+
| hello                  |
+------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 7):

`Right` is a good choice but you can also use `substring` like this-

```
SELECT Substring(columnname,-5) as value FROM table_name
```

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT row_id
  FROM column_name
WHERE column_value LIKE '%12345';
```

This will return the "row_id" when "12345" is found to be the tailing suffix of the "column_value" within the "column_name".

Comment: This is good answer for those who wants to apply the filter within the WHERE clause.

Answer (score 1):

And if you want to get a dinamic number of right characters after a character:

```
SELECT TRIM( 
    RIGHT(
        database.table.field, 
        (LENGTH(database.table.field) - LOCATE('-',database.table.field)) 
    )
)
FROM database.table;
```

Answer (score 0):

**SELECT** **SUBSTR**('Stringname', -5) **AS** Extractstring;