# How to take last four characters from a varchar?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I'm trying to take the last four characters only from a varchar field. All the rows are different lengths. What function should I be using to accomplish this?

Answer (score 321, accepted):

Right should do:

```
select RIGHT('abcdeffff',4)
```

Comment: Yes you are Right.

Answer (score 31):

```
SUBSTR(column, LENGTH(column) - 3, 4)
```

`LENGTH` returns length of string and `SUBSTR` returns 4 characters from "the position length - 4"

Comment: Welcome to SO and thank you for posting answer. Please consider adding context to your code and also formatting your code.

Comment: There is an off-by-one bug here. Should be `SUBSTR(column, LENGTH(column) - 3, 4)`. If the length happens to be 4, we need to start at position 1 and take 4 chars.

Answer (score 22):

[`RIGHT ( character_expression , integer_expression )`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177532.aspx)

```
SELECT RIGHT(column, 4) FROM ...
```

Also a list of other [string functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181984.aspx).

Answer (score 15):

Use the `RIGHT()` function: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177532(v=sql.105).aspx

```
SELECT RIGHT( '1234567890', 4 ); -- returns '7890'
```

Answer (score 9):

For Oracle SQL, `SUBSTR(column_name, -# of characters requested)` will extract last four characters for a given query. **e.g.**

```
SELECT SUBSTR(description, -4) FROM student.course;
```

Comment: Just to note, this doesn't work for ms sql/sql-server, right?