# SQL 'ends-with' Command

Tags: sql

I'm querying a database to select strings which end in a certain substring, such as `yahoo.com`.

To select equal strings, I would call `select * from users where email='test@yahoo.com'`.

How do I select users whose emails end in `yahoo.com`?

Comment: @PrR3 PostgreSQL 8.4.7

Comment: Doesn't matter the DBMS it's just a LIKE clause.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

If you use a like search and DO NOT put a percent on the end, it is effectively an "ends with".

```
Select * from users where email like '%yahoo.com'
```

Comment: Maybe throw a trim in there for good measure Select * from users where ltrim(rtrim(email)) like '%yahoo.com'

Comment: @mgmedick trims are not necessary unless you are using the char data type, which would be a bad choice for an email column.

Comment: oh I was thinking that if the email was 'blah@yahoo.com                          ' then it wouldn't get it. (there's a space before the end quote)

Comment: Ah ok, trust the data is generally the name of the game. Otherwise your sql can get a bit paranoid lol.

Comment: I suppose a like search where the data has trailing spaces is dependent on the sql engine in use.  With Microsoft SQL Server, trailing spaces are ignored in like searches.

Comment: @mgmedick Actually I just tested and I was wrong. `LIKE` doesn't care about trailing spaces in SQL Server.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use the [`RIGHT()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/right-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) function to return the last *n* characters from a string and check that it matches a given value like this:

```sql
select * from users where right(email, 4) = '.com'
```

Or, if you don't want to manually enter the length, use [`LEN()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/len-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) to compute it:

```sql
select * from users where right(email, len('yahoo.com')) = 'yahoo.com'
```

This approach can sometimes feel nicer when comparing multiple different endings like this:

```sql
select * from users where right(email, 4) in ('.com', '.edu', '.org')
```

**See Also**: [How to take last four characters from a varchar?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12504985/1366033)