# SQL get student with last name 5 characters

Tags: sql

I have a table called Students. 
This table has two fields (ID, Name)

i need to Select all the students whose last name have 5 characters.

For example if i have in this table two records.

```
Student 1: ID - 1
           Name - Roman Jatt Pearce

Student 2: ID:2
           Name: Matt Crazy
```

The query i wanted should only return Matt Crazy since his last name has 5 characters and roman pearce's doesnt.

someone told me to use charindex but i dont really know how to implement it

any suggestion?

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12504985/how-to-take-last-four-characters-from-a-varchar

Comment: First, why are you storing both First and Last Name in a single column?  Second, for `Pearce` how do you know that's the last name?  Why isn't it `Jatt Pearce`?

Comment: Not a good DB design having first and last in one column.  Split them up, then look at the LEN function

Comment: i cant change the database it was given to me by my teacher to solve this exercise.

Comment: @aconstancio --- what is this teacher supposed to be teaching?

Comment: If you use SQL-Server, please edit the question and add the [tag:sql-server] tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the format of `Name` is always "First Middle Last", no names contain spaces, and there are no other things like generation listed (Jr., Sr., et al).

```
SELECT *
FROM Students
WHERE CHARINDEX(' ', REVERSE(Name)) = 6
```

Comment: Also assuming that they use SQL-Server.

Comment: @ypercube Well, he was told to use `CHARINDEX()` so it seemed a safe assumption.  If he needs Oracle or MySQL, `INSTR()`; PostgreSQL, `STRPOS()`; DB2, `LOCATE()`.

Comment: Oh yes, I missed that.

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
select * from Students where Name like '% _____'
```

with dash symbol coming five times