# Php - Search last two characters of input in database based on search form

Tags: php

I've a search page in php and I've already stored many terms in database. 
Suppose i input

```
Helloworld
```

on the search form. I want to find the last

```
2 characters (Ld)  in the database table.
```

I've already tried mb_functions and other alternatives too but nothing worked. I'm badly stuck with this.

Comment: See http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php. Specifically `If start is negative, the returned string will start at the start'th character from the end of string.`

Comment: You could grab the last 2 characters using JavaScript, and pass those characters to your SELECT query.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting last 5 char of string with mysql query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10134609/getting-last-5-char-of-string-with-mysql-query) or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10542310/how-can-i-get-the-last-7-characters-of-a-php-string

Answer (score 0):

I dont know exactly what you need, but this will search for last 2 characters of a string and find a column value in your table that matches it, and then echo it. Also make a check to see if string is longer than 2.

```
$string = 'helloworld';
$newstring = substr($string, -2);

// Connect to database
try {
    $db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=DATABASE_NAME', 'root', 'password123');
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage()."<br>";
    die();
}

// Search for the $newstring in a table
$sql = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE column = :newstring");
$query = $sql->execute(array(
    ":newstring" => $newstring
    )
);

foreach ($sql as $row) {
    $dbstring = $row['column_name'];
    echo $dbstring . '<br>';
}
```

Comment: I've tried your codes and it provides blank page. No Result and no error!

Comment: Did you change table_name to your table name? And column to your column name? And of course your database user/password etc.